# Moodle 3.3 - check if a user is authenticated in Mustache template

Tags: moodle, mustache

I'm creating a mustache template for a Moodle site and want to display some content on the front page but only if the user is not yet logged in. I was hoping I could do something like this in the template:

`{{^usernotloggedin}}
    My content for users not logged in.
{{/usernotloggedin}}`

However I can't find any documentation on the user variables available to mustache to test if a user is authenticated or not.

Any advice of where to look or how to implement this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to adjust the code that calls the template to add that data to the context that is passed to the template. In that case you can use the isloggedin() function to set the value you want to pass to the template.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not quite late to this question by anyhow I'd like to add my answer to this as well

Your mustache files are simple templates which cannot perform logic. What you can do is

in your controller or the file which calls the render function (which renders the mustache file and gives HTML), apply a check there

```
require( '/path/to/moodle/config.php' );

if (isloggedin()) {
echo "you are logged in";
}
```

Once you have applied the check you can send the array with a flag identifier (ONLY TRUE or FALSE) which the mustache files can understand.

for eg
in your controller/block etc you can do the following

```
$tagcloud = core_tag_collection::get_tag_cloud($this->config->tagcoll, $this->config->showstandard == core_tag_tag::STANDARD_ONLY, $this->config->numberoftags, 'name', '', $this->page->context->id, $this->config->ctx, $this->config->rec);
$content = $tagcloud->export_for_template($OUTPUT);
require( '/path/to/moodle/config.php' );

$flag = isloggedin() ? TRUE : FALSE;
array_push($content, $flag);
$this->content->text = $OUTPUT->render_from_template('core_tag/search_course_by_tags', $content);
```

and in your mustache file

```
{{#flag}}
your fancy code here which will onyl work if the user is logged in
{{/flag}}
```